# Why isn't my initial condition added to the array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

So I been working with visual studio and made  the program which calculates the SIR model. Once done, it stores the data into an array and writes its into a CSV file.  Got it working, however it is not storing my initial values into the array. Any thoughts why?

Here's is the method which allows the user to set the initial conditions: *Sj, Ij,* and *Rj* (These are what I want to be added to the Array)

```
        public double SetInit(double Sj, double Ij, double Rj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The variables Suspected (S), Infected (I), and Recover(R) have already been set to {0}, {1}, and {2} respectively. \n", Sj, Ij, Rj);
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to reassign the values?[y][n]");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter either y (for yes) or n (for no)");
                ConsoleKey response;
                do
                {
                    response = Console.ReadKey(false).Key;
                    if (response != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");

                } while (response != ConsoleKey.Y && response != ConsoleKey.N);

                if (response == ConsoleKey.N)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Okay, the conditions wills remain the same\n");
                }

                if (response == ConsoleKey.Y)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please a assign a value for S");
                    String Sinput, Iinput, Rinput = "";
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Sinput = Console.ReadLine();
                    Sj = Convert.ToSingle(Sinput);
                    Sj = Math.Round((Double)Sj, 3);

                    Console.WriteLine("Please a assign a value for I");
                    Iinput = Console.ReadLine();
                    Ij = Convert.ToSingle(Iinput);
                    if (Ij > 0.00)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No initial condition of recovered needs to be l");
                    }
                    Rj = Math.Round((Double)Rj, 3);


                    Ij = Math.Round((Double)Ij, 3);

                    Console.WriteLine("Please a assign a value for R");
                    Rinput = Console.ReadLine();
                    Rj = Convert.ToSingle(Rinput);
                    if (Rj != 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No initial condition of recovered needs to be set to 0.");
                    }
                    Rj = Math.Round((Double)Rj, 3);                    

                    if (Math.Abs(Sj + Ij + Rj) != 1)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Sum of the initial conditions must equal to 1.");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The new values for S, I, and R are {0}, {1}, and {2} respectively", Sj, Ij, Rj);
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

And here is the method which performs the calculation and stores it into the array. Note that *xj* represents the stepsize, which will also be in stored.

```
        public double[,] Solve()
        {

        //data plus one
            double Sjp1 = 0;
            double Ijp1 = 0;
            double Rjp1 = 0;

           double[,] Array = new double[numsteps, 4];
           
            //values to modify the stepsize
            double xj, xjp1;
            xj = x0;

            Array[0, 0] = 0;
            Array[0, 1] = Sj;
            Array[0, 2] = Ij;
            Array[0, 3] = Rj;

            for (i = 0; i < numsteps; i++) //numstep has bee nset to ten
            {
                //stepsize has been set to 0.001;
                xjp1 = xj + Stepsize; //Updates the stepsize
                xj = xjp1;//

                Array[i, 0] = xj;
                Array[i, 1] = Sj;
                Array[i, 2] = Ij;
                Array[i, 3] = Rj;

                //functions used to calculate Suspected, Infected and Recovered
                double f1 = FunctionStore.Suspected(Sj, Ij);
                double f2 = FunctionStore.Infected(Sj, Ij);
                double f3 = FunctionStore.Recovered(Ij);

                Sjp1 = Sj + Stepsize * f1;//Updates the value of Suspected 
                Sj = Sjp1;

                Ijp1 = Ij + Stepsize * f2;//Updates the value of Infected
                Ij = Ijp1;

                Rjp1 = Rj + Stepsize * f3;//Updates the value of Recovered
                Rj = Rjp1;
            }
            return Array;
        }
```

I've been tweaking things for a while now, but having no success. Was considering of just adding the values directly into the method which writes the file but I would ask if there was a more sophisticated approach that I am missing. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Your `Sj`, `Ij` and `Rj` variables are method parameters. It's not clear how you expect them to make it out of the method. Perhaps you meant them to just refer to existing fields? (It's hard to know for sure as you haven't shown us complete code - a [mcve] is always useful.) If so, I suggest you just get rid of the parameters from the method. (It's also not clear what the method's return value is meant to represent. You always just return 0.)

Answer (score 1):

The variables are stored in the SetInit() function only.

The most common way would be to store the variables outside of the function in class variables.

e.g. `private double Sj;` and then set them inside of SetInit() with `this.Sj = Sj;`